# Scala Play making sense of a new project dependencies?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I downloaded the latest [activator](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Installing) and followed the instructions there to install it and to create a new bare-bones Play project. The new project was created successfully, however, I can't make sense of the dependencies there.

I see the generated file build.sbt containing no dependency to Play:

```
name := """play-template-new"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Instead I see the sbt Play plugin being referenced under `build/plugins.sbt`:"

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
// addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Why are sbt plugins employed and not proper dependencies? How can I add new dependencies e.g. to Slick latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The play sbt-plugin adds library dependencies to play framework. Just by using the plugin, all necessary dependencies are pulled in. You can check how it's done in the [source-code](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlaySettings.scala#L58) of sbt-plugin.

As for adding slick dependency, just add following to your build.sbt file in a normal sbt way as described in [getting started](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/gettingstarted.html).

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.1.0",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! why is that? can't sbt resolve transitive dependencies???

Comment: SBT can do it without any problem. But Play Framework developers picked up the approach as in the plugin and  I don't know their motives. I can see from the source code that it does some condition checks. If one uses Java for example, it pulls in different components. It seems to take the load of specifying the right modules  away from end user.